# Media Library and upload options are missing

Tags: wordpress, image, media

My site is in wordpress and I am stuck in to one problem. 
I want to create a gallery but upload images options are missing.
Please see the attached image.
Please help.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Like what kind of plugins you have installed and which template? Also what have you tried so far to fix this and can you see any errors? This could be a plugin issue.

Comment: I have updated polylang plugin. And I have created many custom post types.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins? You can disable them all, see if the problem persists, then enable them one by one until you find the one causing the issue. Since you have updated Polylang plugin this could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that latest version of wordpress(wordpress 5.3), conflicts with the plugin enhanced media library.
So I deactivated that plugin and now everything work fine.